# Swagger-codegen - How to customize client SDK call names?

Tags: python, sdk, swagger

I’m new to Swagger. I’ve got an existing RESTful API and wish to create a native python wrapper library.

Is it possible to generate the SDK as an object oriented library?

Example:

For requests like

> GET /root/level/{name}/division/{division}

I’m getting generated Python function

```
root_level_name_division_division_get()
```

**Is it possible to generate an object structure allowing workflow like following?**

```
div = root.level[name].division[division]
root.level[name].division[other_division] = div # This is for PUT
```

Comment: Did you specify `operationId` for the operations in your API definition?

Comment: No. Not yet. I'm total newbie and I actually got my swagger.json from other team. What is this "operationId" and how it can help me, I'd be happy to hear or read ... Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swagger Codegen generates method names based on [operationIds](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.2.md#user-content-operationid), will a fallback to the path names. For example, if your API definition specifies

```yaml
paths:
  /root/level/{name}/division/{division}:
    get:
      operationId: getDivisionById
      ...
```

the generated Python function will be named

```python
def get_division_by_id(self, name, division, **kwargs)
```

> Is it possible to generate an object structure allowing workflow like following?
>
> ```
> div = root.level[name].division[division]
> root.level[name].division[other_division] = div # This is for PUT
> ```

Not out of the box, but you can [create a custom codegen template](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#making-your-own-codegen-modules) that would generate the source code in the format you need.